# How do I add an active class to my li element in html css

Tags: javascript, function, class, html-lists, element

I have been trying to get an active border when selecting a list item. I cannot get the item to show the CSS background-color. how can I get this to work... then a second question I would have is how would I show an alert of which color selected when clicking the button?

here is the javascript that I am trying to incorporate.

```
  $(".swatches li").click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('activeColor');
        $(this).removeClass('activeColor');
   });
```

here is my html

```
<div class="dropdown-container">
  <ul class="swatches" id="swatches">
    <li class="cell">
      NONE
      <div class="colorBox"></div>
      <!--END COLOR BOX-->
    </li>
    <!--END LI-->
  </ul>
  <!--END SWATCHES-->
</div>
<!--END DROPDOWN CONTAINER-->

<div class="buttonForColor">
  <button>
    Change Color
  </button>
</div><!--END BUTTON FOR COLOR-->
```

css

```
.activeColor {
  background-color: red;
}
```

here is my jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/kotten03/02abL9cu/

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the class & then immediately removing it. Remove `$(this).removeClass('activeColor');` from the `click` function to stop this. If you want to clear the previous items with that class, you could use:

```
$(".swatches li").click(function() {
    $(".swatches li").removeClass('activeColor');
    $(this).addClass('activeColor');
});
```

To `alert` the colour, one option would be:

```
$(".buttonForColor button").click(function() {
    alert($($.find('.activeColor')[0]).text());
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/208bq9gy/)

Answer (score 1):

First, you are trying to set a click listener on an array rather than individual elements. Second, you are adding a class and immediately removing it as well.

Try the below code which solves both the issues.

```js
  var elements =   $(".swatches li");
  for (var i = 0, n = elements.length; i < n; ++i) {
   var e = elements[i];
   $(e).click(function() {
          $(this).addClass('activeColor');
     });
  }
```

Comment: That actually makes sense, but for some reason it is not working in my fiddle

Comment: I checked in the fiddle link that you gave. It was working.

Comment: hmmm... not sure why im not getting it to work... the codeis supposed to be outside of the loop function, but can't get it to work.

Comment: okay these work. i needed to switch the javascript over to JQuery